# A batch file to download and delete files from a server

Tags: batch-file, download, ftp, delete-file

How can I write a MS dos ftp batch file to:

1. download files from the server to my local pc
2. remove these files from the server after download

**Edit:**

So far I have...

Batch file:

> ftp.exe -s:ftp.txt

FTP.txt:

> open domain.com
>
> usernamehere
>
> passwordhere
>
> cd /httpdocs/store/files
>
> need get, list and delete commands here??
>
> quit

Comment: Impossible to answer without more information about your server and what protocols it supports.

Comment: @Pekka: I find that "ftp" is quite clear when it comes to protocols. It is even in the tags for the question.

Comment: @Fredrik yeah, I overread that part. My bad

Comment: are the files you want to download known to you, or do you have to list them?

Comment: @Pekka, All i know is the files end in .xml but there could be any number of these

Answer (score 1):

The ftp.exe program can take [a sort of script file as input](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/77.cfm) (that example uploads a file, but I guess to get the idea), so you should probably be able to create a script for the commands that you need to carry out, and then have a batch file launch ftp.exe with the appropriate input.

Answer (score 1):

From one of my cuestions in other post.

```
user-name
user-password
lcd c:\localfolder-where-download
cd remote-folder
mget .  
mdelete \\remote-folder\ .
quit
```

1 & 2 line , your credentials
3 - line local folder where the ftp can download the content
4- line - remote folder if needed
5- line - get al content to your local folder
6- line - delete all content from your remote folder
7- line quit!

Answer (score 0):

you can download [ncftpput/ncftpget](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/). With `ncftpget`, there's option to remove remote files after downloading.